# Display RTSP on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, rtsp

I'm looking for a way to display a RTSP stream on chrome in windows. I have found how to do it with firefox. But I am unable to do it on chrome. I've been looking for several days and all google paths lead to no answer.
I have tried the  following: 
1. html5_rtsp_player on git but it is not clear enough from their description how to get it running. I couldn't even get their example running. It says I need to compile some ES5 file, but it doesn't give the expected file as a result. Moroever, it should be used side by side with some kind of server that I didn't quite get what it needs to do.
2. WebRTC - I saw on several places this could help, and on others I saw it doesn't support IP Cam only web cams.

Edit:
I already have a software that establishes a p2p connection between the ip cam and the client. It provides me with an rtsp address which I can watch using VLC. What I would like to do is display that RTSP link inside a browser. I am not sure if I still really need server. The way to view it on firefox is using some plugin that is unavailable and not supported on chrome.

Comment: You can't do it directly - in the research you've done you already see that tml5_rtsp_player needs a server. Just setup a ffmpeg or VLC or any commercial product as a server and transcode the RTSP to HTML5 compatible fragmented MP4.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. But I still don't understand how to do that. I don't understand what I need to be listening to on that server, and what I need to return. I will appreciate further help.

Comment: Here is an example with webm (https://www.virag.si/2012/11/streaming-live-webm-video-with-ffmpeg/), that should get you started. You should then switch the format line from webm to mp4 and tune x264 parameters to get what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to get html5_rtsp_player working, please follow these steps:

1. To get the bundle file, navigate to src folder and execute the command 
   *webpack --config webpack.config.js* . This produces test.bundle.js which you can include in the html file where you include your rtsp stream.
2. Install ws-rtsp-proxy server (Either on Ubuntu 16.04/Fedora). I tried on Ubuntu 16.04(The server doesn't get installed on Ubuntu 14.04 or 12.04). Steps are mentioned in the link: https://github.com/SpecForge/html5_rtsp_player
3. Change the port in /etc/ws_rtsp.ini(say 8181) and start the server.
4. Add the websocket url config property in test.js
   Example: rtsp.RTSP_CONFIG['websocket.url'] = "ws://172.30.5.220:8181/ws";
5. Re-run the *webpack --config webpack.config.js* for the changes to reflect. To verify, the websocket url added in test.js should reflect in test.bundle.js